# How to bind custom style in b-col (bootstrap-vue) element?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

I need to add custom style to my `<b-col />` element like below:

```
<b-container fluid class="bootstrap-container">
    <b-row id="plan-execution">
        <b-col :style="executionProgress" >Hello!</b-col>
    </b-row>
</b-container>
```

In the `executionProgress` variable it stores my previously calculated styles eg:

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2) 0% , rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2) 55.00%, rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.0) 57.00%) no-repeat
```

(The style is calculated depending on the data collected from the API)

I tried: `:style=""`, `v-bind:style=""` but no effect.

In code below binding style works perfect

```html
<table class="sah-table">
    <tr id="plan-execution">
        <td :style="executionProgress">Hello!</span></td>   
    </tr>
<table>
```

Short question: How I can bind my previously populated style to `<b-col />` element?

Comment: Could you provide a *runnable* [mcve]? At first glance, it looks like `executionProgress` is not what you think it is when applied.

Comment: I forgot to add the function that calculates the ```executionProgress ``` variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding `:style` as string doesn't seem to work on Bootstrap Vue components. You can pass styles to them using an object, with camel-cased CSS properties (i.e. `marginTop`, `backgroundImage`, etc...) and string values. In your case:

```
executionProgress: { 
  background: 'linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2) 0% , rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2) 55.00%, rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.0) 57.00%) no-repeat'
}
```

See it working:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '#appTemplate',
  data: () => ({
    executionProgress: {
      background: 'linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2) 0% , rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2) 55.00%, rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.0) 57.00%) no-repeat'
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.container {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.css" />
<script src="//polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es2015%2CMutationObserver" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>

<script id="appTemplate" type="text/template">
  <b-container class="bv-example-row">
    <b-row>
      <b-col>1 of 3</b-col>
      <b-col>2 of 3</b-col>
      <b-col :style="executionProgress">3 of 3</b-col>
    </b-row>
  </b-container>
</script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

---

A quick test shows us string notation on Vue components works, so this is a Bootstrap Vue specific problem:

```js
Vue.component('testComponent', {
  template: '#testTemplate',
  props: {
    style: {
      type: String | Object,
      default: ''
    }
  }
})
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '#appTemplate',
  data: () => ({
    stringStyle: 'background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2) 0% , rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2) 55.00%, rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.0) 57.00%) no-repeat'
  })
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<script id="appTemplate" type="text/template">
  <test-component :style="stringStyle" />
</script>
<script id="testTemplate" type="text/template">
  <div :style="style">
    <slot>test</slot>
  </div>
</script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

---

Edit: Filed it as a Bootstrap Vue bug [here](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/3431).

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem a little differently than @Andrei Gheorghiu suggested.

I used "normal" `<div class="col" />` instead of `<b-col />` and works. 
My solution:

```
<div class="container sah-table">
    <div id="plan-execution" class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12" :style="executionProgress">Hello</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

my `executionProgress` variable I calculate:

```
        calculateExecutionProgress: function(progress: number) {
            let alpha = '0.2'

            this.executionProgress = 'background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 255, 0, ' +  alpha + ') 0% , rgba(0, 255, 0, ' +  alpha + ') ' + (Math.min(progress,1) * 100).toFixed(2) + '%, rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.0) ' + ((Math.min(progress  + 0.02, 1)) * 100).toFixed(2) + '%) no-repeat';
            console.log(this.executionProgress)
        },
```

and it works too.

I don't like not knowing what I'm doing wrong, I have two solutions now :)

Comment: If you use DOM elements you can use string, indeed. But `style` implementation in Bootstrap Vue components requires it to be object, so your `style` can be merged with Bootstrap Vue's. Both solutions are good, as they both work (now you know the cause). And, btw, you can very easily change yours to return an object (which works on both DOM and components).

Comment: I've made a quick test (and added it to the answer) with a custom Vue component. It looks like Vue allows `string` styles in components, it's a Bootstrap Vue specific problem.